# Difference in model feature importance and SHAP summary plot

Tags: catboost, shap

I have been playing around the toy dataset to understand more about shap library and usage. I found this issue that the feature importances from the catboost regressor model is different than the features importances from the summary_plot in the shap library.

I am analyzing the feature importance from the model.feature_importances_ on X_train set and the summary plot from shap explainer on X_test set.

Here is my source code -

```
import catboost
from catboost import *
import shap
shap.initjs()
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X,y = shap.datasets.boston()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

# Train Model
model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=300, learning_rate=0.1, random_seed=123)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose=False, plot=False)

# Compute feature importance dataframe
feat_imp_list = list(zip ( list(model.feature_importances_) , model.feature_names_) )
feature_imp_df = pd.DataFrame(sorted(feat_imp_list, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True) , columns = ['feature_value','feature_name'])
feature_imp_df
```

[image]

```
# Run shap explainer on X_test set
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
```

[image]

Why does DIS show up at rank 3 in the feature importance plot from Model but shows up at rank 7 in the summary plot from the SHAP library?

Answer (score 4):

Feature importance are always positive where as shap values are coefficients attached to independent variables(it can be negative and positive both).

Both are give you results in descending order:
-In Feature Importance you can see it start from max and goes down to min. Its sum necessarily need to be 100(i.e.100%) in any case.
-For shape values it just the coefficient attached to that particular feature. This is also in descending order (start from highest coefficient to lowest value). Its sum can be anything in real line(for any case).

P.S. you can compare these shap coefficients with coefficient from logistic regression model for better understanding.

Cheers!

Comment: thank you for answer. I have a few more questions - you mentioned that shap values are co-efficients. With regards to this, 1.) how can we see the co-efficients value for each feature? 2.) How are these co-efficients computed? Is there a sample link / blog post where I can check this out?

Comment: I am dropping the links. you can have a look.
1.  [Link](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) 
2.  [Link](https://towardsdatascience.com/explain-your-model-with-the-shap-values-bc36aac4de3d)

Comment: I'm also confused about the difference in order between CatBoostRegressor's Feature Importance and Shap. If anyone could expand on that issue it would be very interesting.

Comment: CatBoostRegressor's Feature Importance - The value that states how much importance of  a specific feature. It doesn't tell you the elasticity of the feature rather it tell contribution in model building whereas shap values is nothing but elasticities of the features (It can be negative/positive ) but feature importance is always positive (sum =1, always)

Comment: @Amit Kumar...nice answer. I Googled this a few times and found no satisfactory response until I stumbled on your answer. Thanks for sharing this!